# Bulk pdf generation process

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssis, msbi

I am currently working on Generating PDFs. I have a requirement to generate bulk pdfs (around atleast 25000 pdfs) with each pdf of 3 to 5 pages with better performance.I have two options

1. SSRS
2. C# with Parallel Processing

Suggest me Which is better option for PDF generation.

Answer (score 3):

Both :)

Write a C# program that uses the SSRS `ReportExecutionService.Render` method to render your 25,000 reports. This gives you the ability to control file naming, location, etc, in C# while still using SSRS for reporting ease and flexibility for PDF generation.

The MSDN site [has some code to get you started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx).